# SUM() not working correctly when left joining Many to Many table

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

Note: I see similar SQL questions but nothing specific to MySQL on how to solve this issue.

I have the following query which sums a product value by day for a period based on the sale date from the sales table, products can be filtered based on categories which is why I need to have the left join, categories also need to be displayed along with the rest of the information. Due to project requirements I can not do any processing outside of this MySQL query.

```
select `sales`.`sell_date` as `date`, SUM(product_value.value) as value from 
   `sales` left join `products` on `sales`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` left join
   `product_value` on `product_value`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and 
   `sales`.`sell_date` BETWEEN product_value.date_from AND 
   IFNULL(product_value.date_to, '2999-01-01') 
   left join `product_product_category` on `product_product_category`.`product_id` 
   = `products`.`id` left join `product_categories` on 
   `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = `product_categories`.`id` 
   left join `users` on `sales`.`seller_id` = `users`.`id` 
   where `sales`.`sell_date` between "2016-02-01" and "2016-02-29" and `product_value`.`deleted_at` is null 
   and `products`.`id` in ("178") and `sales`.`deleted_at` is null group by 
  `sales`.`sell_date` order by `sales`.`sell_date` asc
```

The above query will get a sum which is doubled or trippled when there is two or three categories for a product. Categories can be things such as color, size, etc.

The sum works fine when I remove the following from the query which has lead me to believe that the many to many relationship here is causing the issue.

```
left join `product_product_category` on `product_product_category`.`product_id` =
 `products`.`id` left join `product_categories` on
 `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = `product_categories`.`id`
```

**How can I prevent this left join from causing my SUM() to give me the wrong total value?**

Using Distinct on product_value.value will not work as product values can be the same for many products.

My tables

sales

```
ID | sell_date  | product_id
----------------------------
2  | 2016-02-15 | 178
```

product_value

```
ID | value | date_from  | date_to    | product_id
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 500   | 2016-01-01 | NULL       | 178
2  | 500   | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-01 | 392
```

products

```
ID | name
----------
178  | ProductName
```

product_product_category

```
product_id | product_category_id
--------------------------------
178        | 1
178        | 2
```

product_categories

```
ID | name
---------
1  | Red
2  | Large
```

So to make this clear, if I run the above query on these tables I would get value = 1000 but value should be 500. **How can I make sure SUM() shows the correct value when joining many to many relationships?**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `left join` and add filters in `where` as subquery

```
...
where
...
and exists (
    select 1
    from `product_product_category`
        inner join `product_categories` on `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = `product_categories`.`id` 
    where `product_product_category`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        and ....
        and ....
)
...
```